# Big Query Read using Serializable Function - How to get NUMERIC type from GenericRecord

Tags: java, google-bigquery, apache-beam

Hi,

I'm using Beam to read from a BQ table and saw that read() using a SerializableFunction has better performance than readTableRows(). Following the example at https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.20.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html#read-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction-

My Big Query columns are:

```
|Field name | Field type|
|Date_Time  | TIMESTAMP |
|Simple_Id  | STRING    |
|A_Price    | NUMERIC   |
```

My code looks like:

public class ConvertBQSchemaRecordToProtoDataFn
        implements SerializableFunction {

```
@Override
public ProtoValueType apply(SchemaAndRecord schemaAndRecord) {
    GenericRecord avroRecord = schemaAndRecord.getRecord();

    long dateTimeMillis  = (Long) avroRecord.get("Date_Time");
    String simpleId  = avroRecord.get("Simple_Id").toString();
    double aPrice  = convertToDouble(avroRecord.get("A_Price").toString());
```

The long and String are fine.  However, when I try to convert the NUMERIC type, the GenericRecord (from the debugger) shows it as a HeapByteBuffer which you can't cast.  I'm not sure how to get the value of "A_Price":

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJkc2.png)

The calling pipeline code looks like:

```
PCollection<ProtoValueType> protoData =
        pipeline.apply("BigQuery Read",
                       BigQueryIO.read(new ConvertBQSchemaRecordToProtoDataFn())
                               .fromQuery(sqlQuery)
                                .usingStandardSql()
                       .withCoder(ProtoCoder.of(ProtoValueType.class)));
```

I'm not sure if the Coder is used or not.  ProtoValueType is a protobuf generated binding class.

My question is:  How do I get the value of the NUMERIC type from GenericRecord (which I think is an Avro object)?

Any help appreciated.  I can get the row using readTableRows(), which all comes back as strings so I'm not looking to understand that method.

Comment: Just for clarification, you are reading from BigQuery and where are you writing the output ?

Comment: Hi Alexandre, I'm reading from BigQuery and transforming the rows into a protobuf object that I will pass into another function (for instance, averaging the aPrice values).  The output could be the average values, or something else (still writing the pipeline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GenericRecord field corresponding to `NUMERIC` fields have some additional properties, that you can use to parse a `NUMERIC` as a `java.math.BigDecimal`.

The schema of such a field will be of type `BYTES`, and something like the following:

```
{"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":38,"scale":9}
```

I have just published a blog post explaining how to use those properties in the schema to transform the array of bytes in to `java.math.BigDecimal`:

https://medium.com/@iht/reading-numeric-fields-with-bigqueryio-in-apache-beam-23273a9d0c99

Comment: Thanks Israel, this is exactly what I was looking for! Not sure how to "approve" or vote for the answer, but case closed. ;)

Comment: I think you can accept my answer as "answer of your question". More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks again Israel! Done ;)